# IOS/Swift: Pass Object in tableview to detail view controller

Tags: ios, swift, segue, indexpath

I am trying to grab an object from a tableview and pass it to a detail view, something I know how to do in Objective-C but am learning for first time Swift.  However, my code is not getting the row from the index path or object.

Here is my code.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        print("segue")
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail"{
                    if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? detailVC {
                                    )
                if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {      
                    print("row%@",indexPath)//Prints as nil
                let thisItem = myItems[indexPath.row]//never gets here
    destinationVC.item = thisItem 
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Can anyone see why I am not getting the row or the object?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

**Edit:**

I got it to work with following:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {

            let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow! as NSIndexPath

            let anItem: myItem = myItems[indexPath.row];

            let destVC = segue.destination as? detailVC
            destVC?.item = anItem

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Implement `UITableViewDelegate` method,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item = myItems[indexPath.row]
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: item)
}
```

then implement below,

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showdetail" {
        let detailController = segue.destination as! detailVC
        detailController.item = sender as! Your_Item
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is Your_Item here?  Does it remember item=myItems[indexPath.row] from other method?

Comment: it is your object

Comment: The sender here seems to be the UITableCell, not the object.  So it is trying to pass the tablecell to the destinationVC, not the object:we are sending%@ Optional(<UITableViewCell: 0x102051400; frame = (0 0; 280 44); text = 'Testing 12'; clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x170036a20>>)

Comment: It will not be UITableViewCell, it will be object

Comment: What is there in myItems array?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use these methods to save the value of the selected row or item? and then perform segue?

```
tableView(_:didDeselectRowAt:)
tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)
```